# Delegate assign issue "sometimes"

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, async-await

In my app I got this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : A delegate was assigned when not
>   allowed.

this is the code:

```
IAsyncOperationWithProgress<uint, uint> _socketWriter;
_socketWriter = _socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(sendBuffer);
_socketWriter.Completed = OnSocketWriterCompleted;
```

the real problem is that if i run the app 100 times i got this error only 1 or 2 times, so is a very rare problem.

any idea how to get more information about this issue or how to solve this problem?

Comment: Probably has something to do with you not awaiting your awaitables.

Comment: Are you using `_socketWriter` anywhere after that? This error seems to happen when the `Completed` callback is set more than once (manually or by the use of the `await` keyword)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error caused by awaiting the same async object twice https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210226-00/?p=104911

If the async object completes, then it is safe to await it the second time, hence the error is not consistently reproducible.

You are probably awaiting the `_socketWriter` somewhere after already setting the completion handler:

```
_socketWriter.Completed = OnSocketWriterCompleted;
```